# How reliable is checkdnd.com API when it comes to checking "Do Not Disturb" contacts (not a country specific)

Tags: java, php, html, sms, call

I am working on an application where I have to send bulk messages, the only constraint is to ignore those recipients who has enabled their DND.

I am Planning to use checkdnd.com as it checks for worldwide contacts (not a country specific), is it reliable enough? Has anyone used it in their application before? Let me know if there are any other options available.